# Report status crontab lines in a log file Linux RedHat

Tags: linux, shell, sed, redhat

I would like to know how to extract the state of crontab.

Currently I have these lines, with the execution off:

crontab -l

```
#* * * * * cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
#* * * * * sleep 15 && curl cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
#* * * * * sleep 30 && curl cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
#* * * * * sleep 45 && curl cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
```

Desire, based on the state of the crontab for these lines, report ON or OFF in a log file.

In this case I must report "OFF"

Instead:

crontab -l

```
* * * * * cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
* * * * * sleep 15 && curl cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
* * * * * sleep 30 && curl cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
* * * * * sleep 45 && curl cd $HOME;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
```

In this case I must report "ON"

They can help me with any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Technically speaking, those are not "ON" or "OFF" jobs, they are "line that defines a scheduled job" and "comment that may or may not contain the text of a scheduled job definition"...

Comment: I known. Then I need: If status crontab -l = #<anything loader_DESA.sh> then write a file with sed = 'OFF'                 if status crontab -l = <anything loader_DESA.sh> then write a file with sed = 'ON'

Answer (score 1):

```
 crontab -l | awk '{if($0~/^ *#/){ print "OFF: " $0 } else print "ON : " $0 }' \
 > cronStatusReport.$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)
```

should produce the output you're looking for.

**output** (from reduced set of your data)

```
OFF: #* * * * * cd /C/Users/Neil_2;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
OFF: #* * * * * sleep 15 && curl cd /C/Users/Neil_2;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
ON : * * * * * sleep 30 && curl cd /C/Users/Neil_2;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
ON : * * * * * sleep 45 && curl cd /C/Users/Neil_2;sh .bash_profile >/dev/null 2>&1;cd /home/gisdesa/GIS/DESA;. ./loader_DESA.sh
```

IHTH

Comment: @user2048092 : Glad this helped. Can you please accept my answer by clicking the check mark by the `^ 0 v` near the top left of my answer. Good luck.